# How can i map data from one file to another based on entering a date and searching for that value in the second file

Tags: excel, vba

1. the user enters a date in the target file(where the macro is)
2. If user enters a date like 12jun23, it should convert it to 12-Jun-23 or any variation
3. search that date in W column in source file (POR file)
4. if there's a row filled with that date, map few of the columns data to my target file.
5. It should map the columns like A column in my file, to B column in the source file.

I'm getting a 1004 error, stating application or object error.

```
Also, tried making some changes, the recent error im getting is: 
When i enter the date, for example 30may23, it should format to 30-May-23, and then search for it in the file.
But its currently formatting to 30-Dec-99.

Sub UpdateData()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRow As Long
    Dim targetRow As Long
    Dim targetDate As Date
    Dim targetDateStr As String
    
    ' Open the source file and set the source worksheet
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\E12\Desktop\FY23.xlsx") ' Update with the path to the source file
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Pull in") ' Update with the name of the source sheet
    
    ' Open your file and set the target worksheet
    Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook ' Update if your file is different
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Sheets("Released") ' Update with the name of the target sheet
    
    ' Prompt the user to enter a date
    targetDateStr = Application.InputBox("Enter the date (DDMMMYY)", Type:=2)
    
    ' Convert the target date string to a valid date format
    On Error Resume Next
    targetDate = DateValue(Replace(targetDateStr, ".", "-"))
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Check if the target date is a valid date
    If IsDate(targetDate) Then
        ' Format the target date to "dd-mmm-yy"
        targetDateStr = Format(targetDate, "dd-mmm-yy")
        
        ' Find the row in the source file based on the date and "Release to Logistics" value
        Dim searchRange As Range
        Set searchRange = wsSource.Columns("W")
        sourceRow = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        sourceRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CDate(targetDate), searchRange, 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' Update the data in your file if a match is found
        If Not IsError(sourceRow) Then
            ' Map specific columns from the source file to your file
            wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, 1).Value = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, 2).Value
            wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, 2).Value = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, 4).Value
            wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, 3).Value = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, 5).Value
            wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, 4).Value = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, 6).Value
            wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, 5).Value = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, 7).Value
            wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, 6).Value = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, 8).Value
            wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, 7).Value = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, 9).Value
            wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, 8).Value = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, 12).Value
            wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, 9).Value = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, 13).Value
            wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, 10).Value = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, 16).Value
            wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, 11).Value = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, 18).Value
            wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, 12).Value = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, 21).Value
            wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, 13).Value = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, 23).Value
            wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, 14).Value = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, 1).Value
          
            MsgBox "Data updated successfully."
        Else
            MsgBox "No data found for the specified date or 'Release to Logistics' value not found."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid date entered. Please try again."
    End If
    
    ' Close the source file without saving changes
    wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, 1).Value = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, 2).Value

Comment: Dim targetRow As Long

Comment: You've declared it, but have not assigned a value to it.

Comment: By the way, sourceRow should be declared as Variant, since Match can return two types of data, that being an error value or a number.  Otherwise, as your code stands, `If Not IsError(sourceRow) Then` will always evaluate to True.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateData()

    Const SRCFILE = "C:\Users\E12\Desktop\FY23.xlsx" ' Update with the path to the source file

    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRow As Variant, targetRow As Long
    Dim arCol, i As Long
    
    ' Prompt the user to enter a date
    Dim targetDate As Date, targetDateStr As String
    targetDateStr = Application.InputBox("Enter the date (DD MMM YY)", Type:=2)
    
     ' Check if the target date is a valid date
    If Not IsDate(targetDateStr) Then
        MsgBox "'" & targetDateStr & "' is not a valid date. Please try again.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        targetDate = DateValue(targetDateStr)
        ' Format the target date to "dd-mmm-yy"
        targetDateStr = Format(targetDate, "dd-mmm-yy")
    End If
    
    ' Open the source file and set the source worksheet
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(SRCFILE)
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Pull in") ' Update with the name of the source sheet
    
    ' Open your file and set the target worksheet
    Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook ' Update if your file is different
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Sheets("Released") ' Update with the name of the target shee
    targetRow = 2 ' as appropriate
  
    ' Find the row in the source file based on the date and "Release to Logistics" value
    Dim rngSearch As Range
    Set rngSearch = wsSource.Columns("W")
    sourceRow = Application.Match(CDbl(targetDate), rngSearch, 0)
    
    ' Update the data in your file if a match is found
    If Not IsError(sourceRow) Then
        ' Map specific columns from the source file to your file
        arCol = Array("B", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "L", "M", "P", "R", "U", "W", "A")
        For i = 0 To UBound(arCol)
            wsTarget.Cells(targetRow, i + 1) = wsSource.Cells(sourceRow, arCol(i)).Value
        Next
        MsgBox "Data updated successfully for " & targetDateStr, vbInformation, "Target Row " & targetRow
    Else
        MsgBox "No data found for " & targetDateStr & " or 'Release to Logistics' value not found."
    End If
    
    ' Close the source file without saving changes
    wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```